# file get content google geocode not working

Tags: php, json, google-geocoder

When i try to execute the code below, it dont work.

```
        $json = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=R%20GRANJAO,%2021&sensor=false&key=MYAPIHERE');
        var_dump($json);
```

The code above return me with "ZERO_RESULTS".

But if i manualy access the link, it returns the contents.

Example below:

[image]

Of course i am using a valid API, because most of the addresses work, but a few, just like this example, dont.

I tried to use urlencode() as well, but it doesnt seens to be the problem here.

Comment: Try doing that with curl, setting the Useragent the same as your browser.

Comment: i have already tried with curl, but no success, then i manage to solve it add 'accept-language' on the header

Comment: What do the server logs say why they return something different? Cookies or cached credentials perhaps? Or a redirect?

Comment: i didnt put any effort on server log, because the API return some information,'ZERO_RESULTS'... Its like she was not returning anything to me, it could mean the address didnt really exist, but since it worked manualy, i knew something in the return was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seens that it was necessary to add a header setting 'accept-language'.

```
        $url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false&key=$apiKey";
        $header = array('Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3');
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $response = json_decode($json, true);
```

This solved the issue!